# Set view's direction to the opposite direction of its layout

Tags: android, layout, android-layout-direction

I Have a Relative layout and its direction based on app language (there are two directions: LTR and RTL), and I have one view (CheckBox) inside that layout.
now I want to make the Checbox direction to the opposite direction to its layout.

Any advice?

**Edit**

[image]
when be the layout direction is LTR I want to make this checkbox direction is RTL, as well when be the layout direction is RTL I want to make this checkbox direction is LTR.

Comment: You should add the code of what you're trying to do and possibly an image to indicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
if(config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)
```

to determine wether the LayoutDirection is RTL or LTR and set the position of the Checkbox programmatically.

Here is an example:

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#00CCCC"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hide...">
        </CheckBox>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.androidlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox checkbox;
    RelativeLayout parent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentRelativeLayout);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) checkbox.getLayoutParams();
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        if(config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        }else{
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        }
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    }
}
```